# How can i edit several numbers/words in a txt file using python?

Tags: python, list

I want to rewrite a exisiting file with things like:

```
Tom     A
Mike    B
Jim     C
```

to

```
Tom     1
Mike    2
Jim     3
```

The letters A,B,C can also be something else. Basicaly i want to keep the spaces between the names and what comes behind, but change them to numbers. Does someone have an idea please? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: do you know how to read and write files? here you have a tutorial https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/

Comment: A) How is the file structured? Ideally, you'd have a known deliminator (like the comma in a CSV) so you could say "I need to update the 3rd column" etc.
B) How do you know what the final output is meant to be? Are you adding an index or doing some more involved value mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your first and second columns are separated by a tab (i.e. `\t`)?

If so, you can do this by reading the file into a list, use the `split` function to split each line of the file into components, edit the second component of each line, concatenate the two components back together with a tab separator and finally rewrite to a file.

For example, if `test.txt` is your input file:

```
# Create list that holds the desired output
output = [1,2,3]

# Open the file to be overwritten
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Read file into a list of strings (one string per line)
    text = f.readlines()

# Open the file for writing (FYI this CLEARS the file as we specify 'w')
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Loop over lines (i.e. elements) in `text`
    for i,item in enumerate(text):
        # Split line into elements based on whitespace (default for `split`)
        line = item.split()
        # Concatenate the name and desired output with a tab separator and write to the file 
        f.write("%s\t%s\n" % (line[0],output[i]))
```

Comment: WOW thx for your answer, its working. If i want to add the name to a array like Tom array[1] how should i do it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean? Do you want to save "Tom" and "1" to an array?

Comment: I mean if i want to replace A B C with certain words combined with up counting numbers, how should i do it? Because im using this python program to do the tipping work for me for other programming uses. And there behind the variable names are exactly array[i], with i need to be the up counting numbers.

Comment: I would read up on python [dictionaries](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/) and [lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/)/[tuples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tuples/) - any of those or a combination of those will likely do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your first and second columns were separated by a spaces in the file.

You can read the file contents into a list and use the function replace_end(line,newline) and it will replace the end of the line with what you passed. then you can just write out the changed list back to the file.

```
""" rewrite a exisiting file """

def main():
    """ main """
    filename = "update_me.txt"
    count = 0
    lst = []

    with open(filename, "r",encoding = "utf-8") as filestream:
        _lines = filestream.readlines()
        for line in _lines:
            lst.insert(count,line.strip())
            count += 1
            #print(f"Line {count} {line.strip()}")
        count = 0

    # change the list
    for line in lst:
        lst[count] = replace_end(line,"ABC")
        count +=1

    count = 0

    with open(filename, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as filestream:
        for line in lst:
            filestream.write(line+"\n")
            count +=1

def replace_end(line,newline):
    """ replace the end of a line """
    return line[:-len(newline)] + newline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```